# System Restore past Windows 7 Upgrade

Tags: windows-7, upgrade

I received an upgrade cd from HP back in June to upgrade from Vista to Windows 7.  I now want to do a system restore, but it looks like it only goes as far back as my upgrade.  Is there a way to go beyond this, or am I now limited to my this point?

Answer (score 2):

If you performed an upgrade and not a new installation, Windows 7 may appear in the add/remove program list (This is how it used to work - not tested since XP).

However, as much as Windows Vista and Windows 7 share many features, there are significant differences and going back to previous restore points are simply not possible.

System Restore is designed to remove programs and settings that have been accidentally created since, so if you have a specific problem, you can ask here and I am sure someone will try to help you.

If you just want to go back to Vista, I recommend using your original repair disk.